# Relative select field

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

`NIC (nic_id,nic_no,name,address)`
and

`License (license_id,license_no,type,expiry_date)`.

I am using `cnic_id` as foreign key in license table.

On the license page there are fields that are displaying License ID,License NO, NIC NO(Select box),License type, Expiry Date.
Nic no are from nic table displaying nic no's.

I want a license_no to be assigned to a unique nic_no, so that one license no has only one nic_no.

The system does not allow assignment of two nic no to one license no.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ? {x} are your variabels

```
INSERT INTO License(cnic_id, license_id,license_no,type,expiry_date)
SELECT {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM License WHERE cnic_id = {1})
```

Comment: I want only those cnic_no in select box which are not assigned to any license_id